# How to test AngularJS controller with JsTestDriver?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, js-test-driver

I have the following code:

```
function TestStats($xhr) {
    $xhr(
            'GET',
            '/test-dashboard/get-projects.json',
            angular.bind(this, function(code, response) {
                this.projects = response.projects;
                this.projects.splice(0, 0, undefined);
            }));

    this.$watch('project', angular.bind(this, function() {
        this.testClassStats = undefined;

        if (this.project) {
            $xhr(
                    'GET',
                    '/test-dashboard/get-test-stats.json?project=' + this.project,
                    angular.bind(this, function(code, response) {
                        this.testClassStats = response.testClassStats;
                    }));
        }
    }));
};

TestStats.prototype.greet = function(name) {
  return "Hello " + name + "!";
};

TestStats.$inject = ['$xhr'];
```

and the following test:

```
TestDashboardUnitTest = TestCase("TestDashboardUnitTest");

TestDashboardUnitTest.prototype.testAoeu = function() {
    var xhrStub = function(method, url, callback) {
    };
    var testStats = new TestStats(xhrStub);
    assertEquals("Hello World!", testStats.greet("Aoeu"));
};
```

and the following config:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
  - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
  - http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.17.min.js
  - web/*.js
  - test/*.js
```

When I run the test, JsTestDriver outputs:

```
Total 1 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 0; Errors: 1) (0.00 ms)
  Chrome 13.0.782.112 Linux: Run 1 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 0; Errors 1) (0.00 ms)
    TestDashboardUnitTest.testAoeu error (0.00 ms): TypeError: Object #<TestStats> has no method '$watch'
      TypeError: Object #<TestStats> has no method '$watch'
          at new TestStats (http://127.0.0.1:9876/test/web/test-dashboard.js:13:10)
          at [object Object].testAoeu (http://127.0.0.1:9876/test/test/test-dashboard-unit-test.js:9:21)

Tests failed: Tests failed. See log for details.
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/tutorial/step_05

```
scope = angular.scope();
$browser = scope.$service('$browser');

$browser.xhr.expectGET('phones/phones.json')
    .respond([{name: 'Nexus S'},
              {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);
ctrl = scope.$new(PhoneListCtrl);
```

Don't do the usual thing and pass in mocks.  Instead, let the injection system do the work.

Also, be sure to load angular-mocks.js in the jsTestDriver.conf file.

Comment: Yep, this is the right approach to test controller which uses scope's api like `$watch`.

Comment: "Also, be sure to load angular-mocks.js in the jsTestDriver.conf file." Can you expand on this? Where is this .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Angular does, but it seems to me that your problem is in this block of code:

```
this.$watch('project', angular.bind(this, function() {
    // snip
}));
```

When you are calling `this.$watch` method, you are calling a method of an object instance of a class `TestStats` - the class that is described in the first block of code you provided. I don't see a method called `$watch` anywhere there, maybe you need some other object reference, not `this`?